# Uncaught Error: No such template: content at blaze.js?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, masonry

I read through the other possible related links to try to figure this out.  I will list out my code and the packages I presently have.  The issue is, I only got these errors after I tried to add Masonry to my template.  Am I not referencing something right?  What could I be missing.

```
<template name ="snippets">
    <div class="container">
        {{#masonryContainer id='MasonryContainer' columnWidth=25 transitionDuration='0.1s'}}
        {{#each snippets}}
                {{> snippet}}
        {{/each}}
        {{/masonryContainer}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name ="snippet">
        {{#masonryElement 'MasonryContainer'}}
        {{#if isLink}}
            <a href={{URL}}>
            <div class="snippet bordered">{{text}}</div>
            </a>
        {{else}}
             <div class="snippet bordered">{{text}}</div>
        {{/if}}
        {{/masonryElement}}
</template>
```

The page will load and the list of errors in the console looks like this:

```
blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3212 Uncaught Error: No such template: content
    at blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3212
    at Blaze.View.<anonymous> (spacebars.js?hash=ebf9381e7fc625d41acb0df14995b7614360858a:68)
    at blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1934
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3744)
    at blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1932
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2271)
    at viewAutorun (blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1931)
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:339)
    at new Tracker.Computation (tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:229)
    at Object.Tracker.autorun (tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:613)
(anonymous) @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3212
(anonymous) @ spacebars.js?hash=ebf9381e7fc625d41acb0df14995b7614360858a:68
(anonymous) @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1934
Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3744
(anonymous) @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1932
Blaze._withCurrentView @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2271
Spacebars.include:anonymous @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1931
Tracker.Computation._compute @ tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:339
Tracker.Computation @ tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:229
Tracker.autorun @ tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:613
Blaze.View.autorun @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1944
(anonymous) @ spacebars.js?hash=ebf9381e7fc625d41acb0df14995b7614360858a:67
fireCallbacks @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2014
Tracker.nonreactive @ tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:640
(anonymous) @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2011
Blaze._withCurrentView @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2271
Blaze._fireCallbacks @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2010
Blaze._createView @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2028
Blaze._materializeView @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2073
materializeDOMInner @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1532
Blaze._materializeDOM @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1474
Blaze._materializeDOM @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1483
(anonymous) @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2113
Tracker.nonreactive @ tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:640
Blaze._materializeView @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2079
Blaze.render @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2370
DynamicTemplate.insert @ iron_dynamic-template.js?hash=7644dc7260de827ef1e361a75159fcc8af9fc074:518
Router.insert @ iron_router.js?hash=f36af52c3c2c3d66f1e99d1562e7d6bf92b00c1c:1639
maybeAutoInsertRouter @ iron_router.js?hash=f36af52c3c2c3d66f1e99d1562e7d6bf92b00c1c:1629
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ iron_router.js?hash=f36af52c3c2c3d66f1e99d1562e7d6bf92b00c1c:1627
maybeReady @ meteor.js?hash=6d285d84547b3dad9717a7c89c664b61b45ea3d8:821
loadingCompleted @ meteor.js?hash=6d285d84547b3dad9717a7c89c664b61b45ea3d8:833
```

Comment: How do you import masonry? and from where?

Comment: from here: Atmospherejs.com 
I did a 
meteor add voodoohop:masonrify

Comment: If you remove the masonry element, does it work?

Comment: Yes it works really well without the masonry element.  I can tweak the css to  somewhat make it look like masonry with margins, etc.. but I really want to effectively use the masonry package:  voodoohop:masonrify  I removed and reinstalled the package but still no luck.

Comment: I've tried it and it works fine for me. Are you using anywhere such a template? Are you sure it is coming from the package?

Comment: Yes, the package voodoohop:masonrify is definitly added.  So it should be coming from the package. Is there an extra step I could be missing?

Comment: It is very difficult like this cause much information is missing. Create a new project, add this package first make sure all is working, then piece by piece add the reset of the project related to this problem till you are facing it again, then you would know the cause, if you can't solve it then, come back here and open a new PO with all the details. Hard work I know but will pay off :)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense and is what I plan to do!  Considering that this is a test app, I also figured, I should test a bare bones app and do a test deploy first and come back to masonrify later.  Thank you.

Comment: So heres the thing... I really truly dig Meteor and how easy stuff is!  But... when it comes to deployment, I've spent over 10 hours... pretty much my whole Sunday, trying to figure out an easy way to deploy (not via galaxy, which ends up costing a min of $30 a month)  I already have a hosting services, ... do I need a separate one just for Meteor apps?  Is there a simple way to deploy a Meteor app to my public_html folder of my websitename.com like via ftp or something?